# Jquery selecting one out off multiple classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a drop down list in which option elements have multiple classes. These classes are dynamically generated and assigned so I don't want to hard code.

```
  <select class="currency_switcher">
    <option value="#" class="reset default active" data-currencycode="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="#" class="" data-currencycode="EUR">EUR</option>
  </select>
```

Basically I want to check if whether the selected option has `active` class. As you can see active is one out of many possible classes assigned to the option. I am doing this on `change` event:

```
if($('select.currency_switcher option:selected').attr('class')=="active")
    {
    alert("Hello");
    }
```

But this returns false even when the current option has active class. So how do I solve this?

Ahmar

Answer (score 2):

Check for active class, using [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/):

```
if ($(this).children('option:selected').hasClass('active')) {
    alert("Hello");
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, I just want to add that the reason trying `.attr('class')=="active"` doesn't work is because it returns all the classes as a string.  For instance, `<p class='active default'>text</p>` would return `"active default"` when using `.attr('class')`. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rf9Zk/)

Comment: @Coda17 Ya that's it, and basically, `hasClass` is checking for index of class in string returned by `className` node property